# How Update JSON with express and Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express

I try to update JSON file in backend with express and display new datas on frontend. But currently when I do request I get good response but data don't change.

Server Express (route) Script to edit JSON:

```js
function editJSON(fr,en,es){
    var obj = {
        list_words: []
    }
    fs.readFile('./assets/words.json', 'utf-8', (err, jsonString) =>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else {
            try{
                obj  = JSON.parse(jsonString)
                obj.list_words.push({fr: fr, en: en, es: es})
                json = JSON.stringify(obj)
                fs.writeFileSync('./assets/words.json',json,'utf-8',function (err){
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('complete');
                })
            } catch (err){
                console.log(" Error parsing JSON", err)
            }

        }
    })
}
```

And below script to send data and other to display.

```js
  methods: {
    async addWord () {
      var obj = {
        fr: this.words_input.fr,
        en: this.words_input.en,
        es: this.words_input.es
      }
      const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/addwords', obj)
      const data = res.data
      console.log(data)
    }
  },
mounted: async function () {
    await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/words.json')
      .then(response => {
        this.words_init = response.data
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('There was an error: ' + error.response)
      })
  }
```

If I restart server after request table with new data is displayed. If you know how I can display informations without restart server this can help me so much.

I tried this

```js
 const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/addwords', obj)
 const data = res.data.list_words
 this.words_init = data
```

With this route

```js
app.post('/addwords',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body.fr)
    const fr = req.body.fr
    const en = req.body.en
    const es = req.body.es
    editJSON(fr,en,es)
    console.log(fr)
    res.send(words)
    res.status(201).send('created User')
    res.end()
})
```

But I got error

> "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

From back

and

> "[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "Error: Request aborted"

From frontend

````js
      const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/addwords', obj)
      this.words_init = res.data.list_words
    ```
with this route everything work But mu new list don't display
````

Comment: I suppose you want your frontend to update after the "/addwords" request. Your "addWord" method does nothing except sending the request, so your frontend won't react. The "mounted" function only gets called when your component is first mounted, so you have no mechanism to update your frontend. One way would be to send your json as a response for "/addwords" and handle the data in your frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return latest JSON on `post` response and then assign it to `this.words_init` variable.

Comment: I try response like this `res.send(words)` with words = require to json and in front : 
`      const data = res.data.list_words
      this.words_init = data
`
But my list is not updated

Comment: @antoinesaintlouis Seems you have required `words` above the `app.post` method which will cache and serve the data on server start. Instead you have to again require the json inside `app.post` method.